# React Native - Strange error caught - {"line":25722,"column":33,"sourceURL":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

My react native application is running on android virtual device (API 23)

Android Gradle Plugin Version - 7.2.0
Gradle Version - 7.4.2

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = "1.5.0"
        RNNKotlinVersion = kotlinVersion
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 28
...
```

}

An http request (http://10.0.2.2:8888/myapp/auth) is made to confirm login to my localhost server.
I get an http response code 500 (email/password is incorrect).
AccessService calls FetchTool to fetch http.
FetchTool throws a new Error('incorrect email/password').
But AccessService receives a ghost different error as described below:

```
LOG ERROR..:{"line":25722,"column":33,"sourceURL":"http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.myapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true"}
```

Why don't I get the error 500 thrown in FetchTool in AccessService's catch?

```
export default class AccessService {

    static confirmLogon(email, password) {

        const login = {
            email: email,
            password: password
        };

        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }

        const uri = properties.appurl + '/auth';

        return FetchTool.post(uri, headers, login)
            .then(credentials => {
                return credentials;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // the ghost error is captured here 
                console.log('ERROR..:' + JSON.stringify(error))
                throw error;
            });
    }

}

export default class FetchTool {

    static post(uri, headers, playload) {
        return this.executeRequest(uri, headers, playload, 'POST');
    }

    static executeRequest(uri, headers, playload, method) {

        if (headers['Content-Type'] && headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json') {
            playload = JSON.stringify(playload);
        }

        const requestInfo = {
            method: method,
            body: playload,
            headers: headers
        }

        //uri = http://10.0.2.2:8888/myapp/auth
        
        return fetch(uri, requestInfo)
            .then(response => {

                if (response.ok) {
                    //some code return json ok
                } else {
                    return response.text()
                        .then(responseText => JSON.parse(responseText))
                        .then(responseObject => {
                            if(responseObject.statusCode === 500) {
                                //the error scenario takes place here
                                throw new Error(JSON.stringify(responseObject)); 
                            } else {
                                // some code
                            }
                        })
                }
            })

    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove JSON.stringify like so:

```
console.log(‘ERROR: ‘, error)
```

And you ‘ll see the error message as expected.